# How to load an image on top of another upon mouseover?

Tags: processing

I'm currently working on a project in Processing where, eventually, I'll use Arduino and an IR sensor to load images on top of a background image when the IR sensor reads different things. So currently I'm trying to code a program where if a certain value is between two values, the program will load a gif (gif1.gif) on top of the background (bground). I'm playing around using mouseX and Y at the moment, because they're very easy to test (if the mouse coords are within two parameters, an image will load).

Here's the current code:

```java
PImage bground;
PImage PictureFrame;
int pointillize = 10;

void setup () {
  size (1920,1080);
  noFill();
  bground = loadImage("background.png");
  PictureFrame = loadImage("gif1.gif");
  background (0);
  image(bground,0,0);
}
void draw(){
  int x = mouseX;
  int y = mouseY;
  int loc = x+y*bground.width;
  noStroke();

  while (loc > 740 && loc < 1170) {
    image(PictureFrame,740,20);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work! Any help?
In case it isn't clear, it loads a background image. I want it to load gif1 WHILE the mouse is between the pixels specified, which is the middle of the image.

Thank you!

Comment: What does this code do instead of what you expected?

Comment: It just doesn't load the gif at all

Answer (score 0):

Please get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). Use the debugger that comes with the Processing editor, or use some `println()` statements to understand what's going on.

In particular, look at this section of code:

```
while (loc > 740 && loc < 1170) {
  image(PictureFrame,740,20);
}
```

Understand that a `while` loop continues to repeat until its conditions are no longer met. And since `loc` is not updated inside the `while` loop, that means the conditions will always be met, and this loop will never exit.

To see what I mean, add a `println()` statement inside the loop:

```
while (loc > 740 && loc < 1170) {
  println("inside while loop");
  image(PictureFrame,740,20);
}
```

You'll notice that this keeps printing out and never stops. Basically you've frozen up your program.

Instead of a `while` loop, my guess is you just need an `if` statement:

```
if (loc > 740 && loc < 1170) {
  println("inside if statement");
  image(PictureFrame,740,20);
}
```

Now this will only execute once per frame, and your code will not freeze up.

Also note that I'm not really sure what you're doing with the `loc` variable. Try using `mouseX` and `mouseY` directly instead.

Comment: Ah okay! I see what you're saying with the while loop. Though if I used an if function, it still doesn't draw the gif image! Is there something wrong with calling it here?

Comment: Like I said, I don't really know what you're trying to do with the `loc` variable. Try something simpler with using `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables directly. Try getting it working with rectangles before you try it with images. If you still can't get it working, please post an updated [mcve] (using rectangles instead of images) in a new question post, and we'll go from there. Good luck.